Linux keepalived vrrp_track_process does not work as expected
keepalived conf on node01:
vrrp_track_process track_haproxy {
      process haproxy
      weight 10
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
        state MASTER
        interface ens33
        virtual_router_id 51
        priority 255
        advert_int 1
        authentication {
              auth_type PASS
              auth_pass mypassword
        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
              10.0.0.20/24
        }
        track_process {
                track_haproxy
        }
}

keepalived conf on node02:
vrrp_track_process track_haproxy {
      process haproxy
      weight 10
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
        state BACKUP
        interface ens33
        virtual_router_id 51
        priority 254
        advert_int 1
        authentication {
              auth_type PASS
              auth_pass mypassword
        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
              10.0.0.20/24
        }
        track_process {
                track_haproxy
        }
}

The problem is when the haproxy service on node01 is stopped, the VIP 10.0.0.20/24 is not removed from node01 then assigned to node02 as I expected.
Please help. Thank you.

The failover works for me without the weight setting in vrrp_track_process.
vrrp_track_process track_haproxy {
    process haproxy
    delay 1
}

The delay setting keeps keepalived from triggering a failover if haproxy is only restarted.
I use keepalived 2.2.7 on Debian.
